# HQL Querying, finding by string idea 

Tags: oracle, hql

Two questions.

1. Is there a way for us to query by substring/contains method or like a search style query or even regular expression matching?
   Without making it case sensitive?!!!
   Example.

Query for: Good Food:

Table contains

1. I like eating Good Food.
2. Blah blah blah.
3. Good Food is great.
4. I like mcdonalds.
5. Food is Good.

The result of results I would recieve is 1,3 the rest is pretty much useless.

---

Second Question.

I have a table with

```
Primary Key      EventId          Message
1                  14             Good Food now
2                  14             Good Food later
3                  14             Good food today
4                  17             scrabble
5                  19             babble
6                  20             squable
```

I pretty much want the event id that is associated when a message contains good food.
So Rather than retrieving 
eventId 3 times.
I just want eventid 1 time with the number 14.
is that possible too?

So in short.


When querying for good food inside a message, can i just get event Id that returns 
14 
rather than 
3 rows of 14?

Comment: hmm k So i figured that you can use the LIKE with '%Good Food%' to find, but how to do the second part?

Comment: never mind, i can use regex_Like for the case sensitivity part. Now how do i do the last part!!!

Comment: second part - select distinct event_id where ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the case sensitivity, you can use ILIKE in some rdbms but as far as i know not in oracle. You can use upper/lower to work around that.

You can use 'distinct' on EventId to solve the last part of your task but be aware that distinct may become expensive. This finding might even lead to rethinking your data model.

Comment: hmm I noticed that it would become expensive, but doing my job there is a lot of repetitive data for finance, and we can't delete financial records. Thanks!

Comment: understood. And you're welcome. The answer ('use distinct') works for you, or are you still struggling?